# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'Capture'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

```
$("#test_point_geck_info")
  .html("<div id='img_1' class='img_1'>" +
     "<img src = " + ROOT_PATH + 
     "/assets/Capture.PNG onclick=PopImage(" + ROOT_PATH + 
     "/assets/Capture.PNG,'xyz')" +
     " style='cursor:pointer;' class=thumbnail width='100' height='100'></div>");
```

Results following on the browser:

```
<img src="/assets/Capture.PNG" onclick="PopImage(/assets/Capture.PNG,'xyz')" style="cursor:pointer;" class="thumbnail" width="100" height="100">
```

function that am calling :

```
function PopImage(imagesrc,caption) {
var PopupImageContainer = new Image();
PopupImageContainer.src = PopupImageSRC;
setTimeout("PopupImageDisplay()",loadDelay);

}
```

Answer (score 5):

`/assets/Capture.PNG` is interpreted as a [regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression) (for `assets`) with `Capture.PNG` as flags - which are invalid. You wanted a string: `'/assets/Capture.PNG'`.

Anyway, you shouldn't use inline event handler attributes - especially when you already have jQuery available. Better:

```
$("#test_point_geck_info").html('<div id="img_1" class="img_1">' +
'<img src = " + ROOT_PATH + "/assets/Capture.PNG" title="xyz" ' +
'class="thumbnail" width="100" height="100"></div>').find("img").click(PopImage);
```

```js
function PopImage(e) {
    var imagesrc = this.src,
        caption = this.title;
    var PopupImageContainer = new Image();
    PopupImageContainer.src = PopupImageSRC;
    PopupImageContainer.onload = function() {
        PopupImageDisplay(PopupImageContainer, PopupImageCaption, PopupImageSRC);
    };
}
```

```css
.thumbnail {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ..... its working after changing it to string :) ... i mean to '/assets/Capture.PNG'

Comment: could you please let me know what s the error here ........getting an uncaught exception error on this line .....  setTimeout("PopupImageDisplay("+PopupImageContainer+"','"+PopupImageCaption+"','"+PopupImageSRC+")",loadDelay);

Comment: It's quite the same error here. Have a look at the string you're producing here (maybe alert it before feeding it into `setTimeout`) and think whether that's valid JS. Then, switch to not using a string at all but [a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).

Comment: I have changed my method call to ..........setTimeout('PopupImageDisplay('+PopupImageContainer+','+PopupImageCaption+','+PopupImageSRC+')',loadDelay); .... but still get the ssame error ... could you please correct me

Comment: I don't see any change (apart from the different string delimiters). Try `alert('eval("PopupImageDisplay('+PopupImageContainer+','+PopupImageCaption+','+PopupImageSRC+')") doesnt work');` to see what's wrong. My answer contains the solution already - use a function that calls `PupupImageDisplay` with appropriate arguments

Comment: alert('eval("PopupImageDisplay('+PopupImageContainer+','+PopupImageCaption+','+‌​PopupImageSRC+')") doesnt work');    this doesnt work too

Answer (score 2):

It occurred for me when incorrectly put some  codes between javascript

Comment: Typical problem when injecting back-end code on inline JavaScript(It's a bad practice anyway).