# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'usuario'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying fill a table with this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = "<c:out value="${lista}"/>";
    $.get(url, function(data){
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        for(var item in json.usuario) {
            var row = $('<tr>');
            row.append('<td>'+json.usuario[item].login+'</td>');
            row.append('<td>'+json.usuario[item].pnome+'</td>');
            row.append('<td>'+json.usuario[item].unome+'</td>');
            row.append('<td>'+json.usuario[item].email+'</td>');
            row.append('<td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-action="'+${editar}+'" data-target="'+json.usuario[item].id+'">Editar</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-action="'+${remover}+'" data-target="'+json.usuario[item].id+'">Remover</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-action="'+${grupos}+'" data-target="'+json.usuario[item].id+'">Permiss&otilde;es</button> </td>');
            $('tbody.content').append(row);
        }
    });
});
```

based on this json string:

```
{"usuario":[{"id":1,"login":"klebermo","pnome":"Kleber","unome":"Mota","email":"klebermo@gmail.com"}]}
```

but when I open the page, besides no row be added to the table, this erro is displayed in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'usuario'
```

Anyone can tell what I am doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I try do the same with this other code, but face the same result:

```
$.each(json.usuario, function(index, item){
    var row = $('<tr>');
    row.append('<td>'+item.login+'</td>');
    row.append('<td>'+item.pnome+'</td>');
    row.append('<td>'+item.unome+'</td>');
    row.append('<td>'+item.email+'</td>');
    row.append('<td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-action="'+${editar}+'" data-target="'+item.id+'">Editar</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-action="'+${remover}+'" data-target="'+item.id+'">Remover</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-action="'+${grupos}+'" data-target="'+item.id+'">Permiss&otilde;es</button> </td>');
    $('tbody.content').append(row);
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

my current code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = "<c:out value="${lista}"/>";
    console.log("url="+url);
    $.get(url, function(data){
        console.log("data="+data);
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
        $.each(json.usuario, function(index, item){
            console.log("index="+index);
            console.log("id="+item.id);
            console.log("login="+item.login);
            console.log("pnome="+item.pnome);
            console.log("unome="+item.unome);
            console.log("email="+item.email);

            console.log('inserindo colunas de dados');
            var row = $('<tr>');
            row.append('<td>'+item.login+'</td>');
            row.append('<td>'+item.pnome+'</td>');
            row.append('<td>'+item.unome+'</td>');
            row.append('<td>'+item.email+'</td>');

            console.log('inserindo colunas dos botões');
            var col = $('<td>');
            col.append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-action="'+${editar}+'" data-target="'+item.id+'">Editar</button>');
            col.append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-action="'+${remover}+'" data-target="'+item.id+'">Remover</button>');
            col.append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-action="'+${grupos}+'" data-target="'+item.id+'">Permiss&otilde;es</button>');

            console.log('inserindo linha na tabela');
            $('tbody.content').append(row);
        });
    });
});
```

the output in the console is:

```
url=/loja/usuario/listagem.json
data=
{"usuario":[{"id":0,"login":"klebermo","pnome":"Kleber","unome":"Mota","email":"klebermo@gmail.com"}]}
index=0
id=0
login=klebermo
pnome=Kleber
unome=Mota
email=klebermo@gmail.com
inserindo colunas de dados
inserindo colunas dos botões
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'usuario'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'Capture'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408817/uncaught-syntaxerror-invalid-flags-supplied-to-regexp-constructor-capture)

Comment: Works for me once I remove the ${} vars from your code - can you post the generated code in a JSFiddle.net like here: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3H6CW/

Comment: this don't work for me, since the json file is dinamically generated and I can only get it through the url /blog/usuario/listagem.json. I try **var url = "/loja/usuario/listagem.json";** instead, but the same error was displayed.

Comment: Don't `jQuery.parseJSON(data)`. Your data is already parsed. Just drop that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more attempts and analyzing the sugestions above, I finally solve my problem, with the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = "<c:out value="${lista}"/>";
    $.get(url, function(data){
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
        $.each(json.usuario, function(index, item){
            var row = $('<tr>');
            row.append('<td>'+item.login+'</td>');
            row.append('<td>'+item.pnome+'</td>');
            row.append('<td>'+item.unome+'</td>');
            row.append('<td>'+item.email+'</td>');

            var col = $('<td>');
            col.append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-action="editar" data-target="'+item.id+'">Editar</button>');
            col.append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-action="remover" data-target="'+item.id+'">Remover</button>');
            col.append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-action="permissoes" data-target="'+item.id+'">Permiss&otilde;es</button>');
            row.append(col);

            row.append('<td></td>');

            $('tbody.content').append(row);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is that you try to parse your JSON twice.

jQuery already parses JSON responses from the server automatically. You don't need to call `jQuery.parseJSON()` in most cases.

Here's what I think is a nicer version of your code:

```
$(function(){
    $.get("<c:out value="${lista}"/>").done(function (data) {
        var $rowTemplate = $(
        '<tr>' +
            '<td></td>' + 
            '<td></td>' + 
            '<td></td>' + 
            '<td></td>' + 
            '<td>' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-action="'+${editar}+'">Editar</button> ' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-action="'+${remover}+'">Remover</button> ' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-action="'+${grupos}+'">Permissões</button> ' +
            '</td>' +
        '</tr>');

        $.each(data.usuario, function (item) {
            var $row = $rowTemplate.clone().appendTo('tbody.content');
            $row.find("td:eq(0)").text(user.login);
            $row.find("td:eq(1)").text(user.pnome);
            $row.find("td:eq(2)").text(user.unome);
            $row.find("td:eq(3)").text(user.email);
            $row.find("button").data("target", user.id);
        });
    });
});
```

Think about using a client side templating engine, it would make much of this unnecessary in the first place.

Comment: Ok, I made some modifications in my code (see update 2), and I see that the correct values are being printed in console, but still get an error almost in the end of execution of the code.

Comment: You are still using `jQuery.parseJSON()`. Why?